Increasing only the numbers inside a String that contains numbers and characters
I am trying to write a method that checks whether a String contains numbers. If it does it should increase the number only.
For example if position is 1:
input possibilities:
ab123
a-b1234
abc234
ab12bc12

output should then be:
ab124
a-b1235
abc235
ab12bc13

Only the last number of the string should be increased if there are more than one number fragments.
public static String incrementNumber(String number, int position){
    
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                String num = matcher.group();
                int inc = Integer.parseInt(num)+position;
                String incrementedString = String.format("%0" + num.length() + "d", inc);
                number = matcher.replaceFirst(incrementedString);
            }

        }

        return number;
    }

At the moment, it does not increment at all. It does not go inside the while.
I cannot tell whether my regex is simply wrong or I am missing a step.

Why are you using \\\\d+ instead of \\d+ ?

Please [edit] the question to show a few examples of input and wanted output.

This should work

neither "\\d+" or "\d+" work so far. it just doesn't enter the while for some reason that I don't understand.

Then the matcher.find() is not matching anything. So the regex does not match the input. I repeat, please [edit] the question to show a few examples of input and wanted output.

I added some more examples now

Here is one way.  Although this could be done with pattern matching and streams the overhead and simplicity of the task indicates an imperative solution.  Having done both this is much more efficient.
This iterates over the characters and either appends the character to the StringBuilder or parses a grouping of digits on the fly, appending that number + 1.  A boolean is used to control the current state between integer parsing and simply character appending.
In case the source String ends with a number, the boolean will indicate whether to add the computed value + 1 to the StringBuilder after the loop has ended.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean digitFound = false;
int value = 0;
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
   
    // The following if/else block simply manages conversion
    // of a series of digits to a number.  When no is digit encountered, 
    // append the number and reset the value and flags.
    
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        digitFound = true;
        value = value * 10 + c -'0';
    } else if (digitFound) {
       sb.append(value+1);
       value = 0;
       digitFound = false;
    }
    
    // if not in midst of processing a number, add character to builder
    if (!digitFound) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
// just in case the a number was at the end of the string.
if (digitFound) {
    sb.append(value+1);
}

prints
23a-b-c35-a-b-c-d45-d23

And here is one example of using streams.

split the string to isolate the numbers among non-numbers and stream
the array.
map to the appropriate result based on whether token does or doesn't match a number.
join the modified stream into a string

String result = Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=\\d)(?!\\d)|(?<=\\D)(?!\\D)"))
         .map(token -> token.matches("\\d+")
                 ? (Integer.parseInt(token) + 1) + ""
                 : token)
         .collect(Collectors.joining());

